# Django & GenericForeignKey from an abstract model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, mezzanine

Looking for a way where and how properly assign related Django model to a generic relationship declared in an abstract model, other models derive from.
Bellow is my attempt to add *ManyToOne* relationship for all descendants deriving from `cartridge.shop.models.Priced` **abstract** model:

```
# cartridge.shop.models unit
# This is a 3rd party module I can't alter sources directly.
# Only monkeypatching or sublclassing are options.
from django.db import models

class Priced(models.Model):
    """
    Abstract model with unit and sale price fields. Inherited by
    ``Product`` and ``ProductVariation`` models.
    """

    unit_price = fields.MoneyField(_("Unit price"))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# Product derives from abstract Priced model
class Product(Priced, …):
    pass
```

```
# my_application.models module
from cartridge.shop.models import Priced, Product
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# Simple example of a django model I wish make ForeignKey
# relationship to from all descendants of Priced model
class VAT(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=36)
    rate = models.DecimalField(
            blank=False, null=False, decimal_places=2, max_digits=2+3)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Value Added Tax")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Value Added Taxes")

Priced.vat_contype = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
Priced.vat_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
Priced.vat = GenericForeignKey('vat_contype', 'vat_id')

Product.vat = VAT()  # Specify the concrete model here ? This way ?
```

I'm also not sure this is the right way how to solve `ForeignKey` relationship for abstract model descendants. Do I make things unnecessarily overcomplicated ? Could by solved with a single `ContentType` without all the `GenericForeignKey` cruft ? Other way ?

I know about subclassing and multi-table inheritance but I'd really like avoid creating extra tables where simple and faster column addition would serve at least as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on your goal.  But, if you want to connect all `Priced` descendants to `VAT` only, then you **don't** need ContentTypes.  I'd recommend that you subclass `Priced` rather than monkey-patching it, because Abstract models don't create database tables.  Then mark the `Priced` subclass abstract, and add a ForeignKey to VAT, like this:

```
# models.py
class VAT(models.Model):
    ...

class PricedWithVAT(Priced):
    vat = models.ForeignKey('VAT')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# This class will have a foreign key to VAT
class Product(PricedWithVAT, …):
    pass
```

And that's it.

You can look at documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/) on how to relate new or existing objects together.

On the other hand, if you want to connect all `Priced` descendants to various models generically, then you **do** indeed want to use ContentTypes.  It's not much more complex:

```
# models.py
class VAT(models.Model):
    ...

class PricedWithGenericRelation(Priced):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# This class can have a foreign key to ANY model, not just VAT
class Product(PricedWithGenericRelation, …):
    pass
```

The [ContentType API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) provides various ways to create the generic relationships between these kinds of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did already got an idea to subclass the base abstract class `Priced` but then I'd also need to create a new derived product model which would create a new table, if I'm not mistaken. But that's what I've tried to avoid. I'm looking how to tweak framework's models by adding a few extra fields - not replacing them nor build tenths of additional tables by subclassing, just for those extra fields which would result in extraneous db joins and slower overall performance.

Comment: I'm relatively new in Django. In Rails this problem is solved very simple by adjusting original model in `class_eval` block and generating a simple migration which adds new fields. No conflicts, no pointless complications.

Comment: Abstract models don't create database tables.  So for example, in the first piece of code I gave above, there would be a table created for Product with all the fields Product both inherits and defines.  There would be no database table for PricedWithVAT, and no extraneous db joins in the way I think you mean.

Comment: If not clear from the original question, I'd like to add a field to existing framework's model, ie. to `cartridge.shop.model.Product`, which (as an extra detail) derives from abstract `cartridge.shop.model.Priced`. Framework's sources can't be altered directly. By creating own derived product model, new table would be created which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: OK, yes I think there is some confusion here.  In that case, I'm unclear on your question, because it asks how to add a (perhaps generic) ManyToOne relationship for all descendants of the abstract Priced model.  Maybe the question needs to clarified and reworded?